# React useScript dependenies

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

The following script is in several places online for a custom hook for loading an external script:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function useScript(src) {
  // Keep track of script status ("idle", "loading", "ready", "error")
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(src ? "loading" : "idle");

  useEffect(
    () => {
      // Allow falsy src value if waiting on other data needed for
      // constructing the script URL passed to this hook.
      if (!src) {
        setStatus("idle");
        return;
      }

      // Fetch existing script element by src
      // It may have been added by another intance of this hook
      let script = document.querySelector(`script[src="${src}"]`);

      if (!script) {
        console.log(`Creating script: ${src}`);

        // Create script
        script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = src;
        script.async = true;
        script.setAttribute("data-status", "loading");
        // Add script to document body
        document.body.appendChild(script);

        // Store status in attribute on script
        // This can be read by other instances of this hook
        const setAttributeFromEvent = (event) => {
          script.setAttribute(
            "data-status",
            event.type === "load" ? "ready" : "error"
          );
        };

        script.addEventListener("load", setAttributeFromEvent);
        script.addEventListener("error", setAttributeFromEvent);
      } else {
        console.log(
          `Using existing script with status: ${script.getAttribute(
            "data-status"
          )}`
        );

        // Grab existing script status from attribute and set to state.
        setStatus(script.getAttribute("data-status"));
      }

      // Script event handler to update status in state
      // Note: Even if the script already exists we still need to add
      // event handlers to update the state for *this* hook instance.
      const setStateFromEvent = (event) => {
        setStatus(event.type === "load" ? "ready" : "error");
      };

      // Add event listeners
      script.addEventListener("load", setStateFromEvent);
      script.addEventListener("error", setStateFromEvent);

      // Remove event listeners on cleanup
      return () => {
        if (script) {
          script.removeEventListener("load", setStateFromEvent);
          script.removeEventListener("error", setStateFromEvent);
        }
      };
    },
    [src] // Only re-run effect if script src changes
  );

  return status;
}
```

My question is whether this is really necessary

> [src] // Only re-run effect if script src changes

I've changed this to [] and it still works fine.

Comment: This is necessary if the script changes when the hook is executed. In my opinion, you should undo your setting, as `src` may be undefined (i.e. not loaded) or may change during the execution of the script (according to line 4 of your code).

Comment: How does adding the src dependency matter as if you run the useScript with a different src it will still create a new hook regardless. I dont know what you mean by the src may change during the execution of the script. Given javascript passes by value, src is immutable for each function call I thought.

Comment: It's like the comment says, passing `src` is necessary in the `useEffect` hook's dependency array if the `src` value changes and you want the effect to run again. If (a) the `src` never changes during the life of the hook or (b) you just don't care if it does and you want the effect to run only once, then omit `src` as an external dependency. Your question of "whether this is really necessary" is subjective and really only up to you to decide if it's necessary or not.

Answer (score 1):

The comment explains it. If you provide only an empty array, the useEffect hook will only be executed once. If there are changes to the "src" later the hook won´t be executed again.

Comment: I dont think thats correct as I called useScript twice when the dependencies was set to [] and it loaded both scripts. Each time the function is called it will create a new useEffect hook from what I understand.

Comment: It is only executed once each time the custom hook is called - yes. So if your `src` is a static value, you do not need it in the dependencies unless it is a state value.